# CodeIgniter Database Session Error

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session

When I try to execute any controller of my CodeIgniter project i receive this error:

```
Fatal error: Class CI_Session_files_driver contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (SessionHandlerInterface::read) in D:\Git\crud-farm\system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_files_driver.php on line 49
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Class CI_Session_files_driver contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (SessionHandlerInterface::read)

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 49

Backtrace:
```

I tried to replace CodeIgniter system files but it didn't work. The problem appears in all projects

Comment: did you change any system files?

Comment: With what are you trying to replace them exactly?

Comment: i dont change anything in system files. I replace system files to other news and doesnt change.

Comment: so did you upgrade from CI 2.0 to 3.0?

Comment: ... and where do you get these new replacements from?

Comment: official page of codeigniter. My version still be the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intermittent PHP Abstract Class Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503240/intermittent-php-abstract-class-error)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Problem solved by restarting Apache.

I attach the url which saved me: http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-64763.html

Comment: I have this problem too. Restarted my apache do the work, but this solution is temporary until that "mysterious" fatal error happen again.

Comment: Really Don't know why this appeared but restarting apache solved the prob.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i did the following

**Restart apache**

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

The files in system should not be modified. My files were modified somehow and were throwing error. I resolved my problem as below.

1. Download fresh codeigniter and extract files
2. copy system files from fresh codeigniter into your project and overwrite the whole system folder.

This should fix your problem.