# CodeIgniter Fatal error: Class CI_Session_database_driver contains 1 abstract method ... Session_database_driver.php on line 49 (Mysterious Error)

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, codeigniter-3, fatal-error

I'm a new user of CodeIgniter. I use CodeIgniter 3.1.3 and been struggling with this *random-timed unknown mysterious fatal error* since almost 2 weeks ago:

p.s. 1) I've been use CodeIgniter for about a month. 2) There is absolutely no error in my code!! So this is a pure system error, not syntax/runtime error.

> **Fatal error:** Class CI_Session_database_driver contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the
>   remaining methods (SessionHandlerInterface::read) in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\pokopoko\system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_database_driver.php**
>   on line **49**
>
> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Class CI_Session_database_driver contains 1 abstract method
>   and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining
>   methods (SessionHandlerInterface::read)
>
> Filename: drivers/Session_database_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 49
>
> Backtrace:

Error text is not always the same! Sometimes:

```
Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php
```

Or

```
Filename: drivers/Session_database_driver.php
```

Or

```
Filename: Session/Session_driver.php
```

Or

```
Filename: core/Input.php
```

Or even

```
Filename: Unknown
```

This error happen at random time, when I reload my website, or even when my website still opened (idle) in browser without I doing anything, my ajax suddenly not work! This happen not only in certain browser! I'm absolutely haven't changed/modified/opened any of CodeIgniter's system files!!

### I have tried:

1. Restarted my apache like suggested here: [CodeIgniter Database Session Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209574/codeigniter-database-session-error). This work but only temporary till this *random-timed unknown mysterious fatal error* happen again.
2. Re-extract fresh downloaded CodeIgniter-3.1.3.zip to my htdocs. Move my project. Still happen!
3. Reinstall my XAMPP (the latest version). This error not appear ... until few hours later, no difference with before.

Few screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What is this? What's the solution? Help me.

## Update:

This is my `autoload.php` & `config.php` content:

my `autoload.php`:

```
$autoload['packages'] = array();
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session'); //I set this
$autoload['drivers'] = array();
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','array'); //I set this
$autoload['config'] = array();
$autoload['language'] = array();
$autoload['model'] = array();
```

my `config.php`:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/pokopoko/'; //I set this
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['language'] = 'english';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';

$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';

$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
$config['log_path'] = '';
$config['log_file_extension'] = '';
$config['log_file_permissions'] = 0644;
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$config['error_views_path'] = '';
$config['cache_path'] = '';
$config['cache_query_string'] = FALSE;
$config['encryption_key'] = '';

$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;

$config['standardize_newlines'] = FALSE;

$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;

$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();

$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;

$config['time_reference'] = 'local';

$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;

$config['proxy_ips'] = '';
```

## Update #2:

I tried @Fairy Dancer's solution. Work about 1 hour, but then this error reappear (Error information changed, but still the same `Session_database_driver.php on line 49`)

[image]

## Update #3:

Yesterday @Rahi and I together has suspected that it maybe a bug between CodeIgniter 3 with PHP >7. There's also other developer with same environment/combination experiencing this issue, like here: https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-66544.html. But I can't downgrade my PHP because I'm using many PHP 7 new shorthands like `??`. If this true, maybe I'll wait until there's another solution, or until CI have newer version with this bug fixed.

Comment: @downvoter I need help. Not a down vote without any comment. T,T I already write my problem here clearly & neat, even I post the screenshots.

Comment: revert back  code to two 2 weeks ago, and see what configuration change you made

Comment: @Deep3015 sadly I have no backup older than week ago ... but this problem is not like that, because this happens to my another stable project too (which is more simple without using setInterval-ed ajax), that's why I'm very sure the problem is not even in my code.

Comment: Can you show your config file here, I mean config.php file code

Comment: @FairyDancer Thanks for the response. I've updated my post with `autoload.php` & `config.php` content (see bottom) :)

Comment: I'm new in CI. I wonder if `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');` is a best practice or not (?) I suspect that line have something to do about this problem. :/

Comment: Just for testing, change session management from files to database and see if error changes.

Comment: @Rahi Thanks for your response. Do you mean `$config['sess_driver']`?

Comment: Yes. Replace $config['sess_driver'] = 'files'; with $config['sess_driver'] = 'database';

Comment: @Rahi Okay. Just tried that. Let see if it work or not.

Answer (score 1):

Change your session

`$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';` to `$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';`

and execute the sql code into your database table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
    `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `data` blob NOT NULL, KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`));
```

Make sure you configure your database in `database.php` file.

Let me know if this not works

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Let me try this! :) I can't tell now it work or no, because the error appear suddenly in random time, so I don't know if maybe few hours later error still appear when I refresh my page. But let see. Hope this really work.

Comment: Codeigniter use to create a session file in your session temp directors with timestamp. Every 2 hrs it used to recreate the instance. Sometimes it show this error while handling the session files. I faced this error two years before for the website called www.iynar.com and it solved for me by using the above method. For creating session files, I format my PC and install wamp server 2.5 and its start working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :D Feel more relieved now.

Comment: Can you please replace your system files in codeigniter with latest version again

Comment: Okay I'll try. :)

Comment: may I asking which PHP version do you use? 7 or 5? I've suspected that this is might be the unsolved bug of combination between CI 3.1.3 and PHP >7. Btw I've deleted & recopy my system `folder`. Apparently error (still) not appear till now.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I'm using PHP 5.5.12 Wamp Server 2.5 Apache version 1.4.9 and MySql 5.6.17

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
```

with

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: almost recent version, 7.1.1

Comment: I am hoping you haven't made any changes in CI core files. Did you?

Comment: Of course I'm never touch any single file in there. I'm only use CI about a month, only changed general configs in application folder such as `database`, `autoload`, `config` (for basepath), and `route` (for default controller).

Comment: This might sound little regressive but can you downgrade your XAMMP so that to have lower PHP version (May be 5.6)? This issue seems to be reported by different developer on PHP 7.

Comment: Actually I had thought about that too! I've also suspected that it might be the bug of combination between CI and PHP 7. I've searched & found there are other people asking this same problem, but I found only several, and there's (still) no any permanent solution. Might be because there's no too many people use combination of CI 3.1.3 and PHP 7 (?)

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem when i use PHP 7.1

But if i downgrade to PHP 7.0 the error is gone...

Just try to use PHP 7.0 and no change in Codeigniter at all.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes it will happen, just restart your server either it will be apache or other than apache, after restarting the server the error will be gone..... depends the the type of the error occurred while working. If the error is occurred automatically while working than it will simply removed by just restarting the server. In my case it will gone by just stopping and starting my local xampp server.

Comment: Don't worry, this problem happened 3 years ago. Now I use CodeIgniter 4 & PHP 7.3 like a charm.